# shorewall - problems with traffic shaping

Tags: tc, shorewall

I'm shaping my traffic such that VoIP calls have highest priority, followed by, VPN, then general network surfing, and lastly, large downloads.

```
[tcclasses]
lw 1 200kbit full 1 tos=0x68/0xfc,tos=0xb8/0xfc
lw 2 full/4 full 2 tcp-ack,tos-minimize-delay
lw 3 full/6 full 3 default
lw 4 full/12 full*8/10 4

[tcdevices]
lw 0mbit 500mbit

[mangle]
MARK(4) 0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       -       -       -       -       -       -       -       504857:5048570:B:B

# general web browsing
MARK(3) 0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       tcp     http,https

# general UDP
MARK(2) 0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       udp
MARK(2) 0.0.0.0/0       $WORK_VPN       tcp     https
MARK(2) $WORK_VPN       0.0.0.0/0       tcp     https

# asterisk
MARK(1) 0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0       udp     $ASTERISK_RTP_PORTS

# google voice (this effectively makes everything equal, only include Google servers here)
MARK(1) 0.0.0.0/0       $GOOGLE_CIDR    udp     $GOOGLE_VOICE_UDP_PORTS
MARK(1) 0.0.0.0/0       $GOOGLE_CIDR    tcp     $GOOGLE_VOICE_TCP_PORTS

# tmobile wifi calling
MARK(1) 0.0.0.0/0       $TMOBILE_UDP_CIDR       udp     $TMOBILE_UDP_PORTS
MARK(1) 0.0.0.0/0       $TMOBILE_TCP_CIDR       tcp     $TMOBILE_TCP_PORTS

# facetime
MARK(1) 0.0.0.0/0       $APPLE_CIDR     udp     $APPLE_FACETIME_UDP
MARK(1) 0.0.0.0/0       $APPLE_CIDR     tcp     $APPLE_FACETIME_TCP
```

When I set the upload bandwidth to some insanely high value, I can notice the bandwidth I'm measuring is what I expect.
If I put it to what it should be (50Mbps) the actual bandwidth I measure on speedtest sites is much, much lower (2-3Mbps).
But, my tcclasses is showing that all traffic can make use of the fast connection when it is available as I have "full" in the configuration for all except *#4*.

What am I missing?

[EDIT]
1. I swapped interfaces to ensure that the driver / device I'm using supports BQL: https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/bloat/wiki/BQL_enabled_drivers/